# Json path expression for getting parent node child based on value matching filter

Tags: jquery, json, web, jquery-selectors, jsonpath

I have the below JSON string. I need to have a JSON path expression such that I get all the "Name" key values that contain the word "Parker", and once I get that node ("key2"), I need to get to its parent node ("MAIN_KEY") which is an array and get all the values in the first element of this parent node.
i.e, output should be as below:

**OUTPUT:**

```
MARK1

MARK11
```

**INPUT JSON:**

```
 {
    "MAIN_KEY": [
        {
            "key1": [
                "MARK1",
                "MARK11"
            ],
            "key2": {
                "Name": "Peter Parker Super"
            }
        },
        {
            "key1": [
                "MARK2"
            ],
            "key2": {
                "Name": "SPIDER MAN"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok": "value"
}
```

Comment: `console.log(data.MAIN_KEY[0].key1[0])` and
`console.log(data.MAIN_KEY[0].key1[1])`

Comment: The search is based on text and not index. It is not so trivial. Follow the process as I mentioned in the question. Need solution without using index.